# How to modify a class in load-scripts.js ?

Tags: javascript

I need to semplify the image edit interface and I need to override a couple of function defined in load-scripts.js in the class imageEdit.

There is a way to override it?
And there is an unminified version of the wp backoffice javascript?

Thank you ^^

Comment: Go to `wp-admin/js` folder. You can find 'image-edit.js' file.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I want to avoid hard code on wp core javascript file or updating I will lose the mods

Comment: Yes, it is not recommended to modify WP core file. You can check if there exist any API available for what you are trying to achieve.